# Controlling a robot arm to follow an SE(3) trajectory

Tags: control, kinematics

I have a 7-DOF robot arm, and I want it to follow a trajectory. This trajectory is defined as a dense sequence of SE(3) waypoints, which were collected by moving the robot arm manually (i.e. by providing a demonstration of a task).

So at each time step, I have a translation error and a rotation error (the error is the distance between the robot's current pose, and the nearest-neighbour demonstration pose). These then need to be converted into a translational velocity and rotational velocity.

But if I just divide each by the time step, (i.e. velocity = distance / time), then this would cause the robot to have a very high velocity when it is further away from the demonstration trajectory. However, I want the robot to move smoothly, with a smooth (ideally constant) translation and rotation velocity. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't just "saturating" those velocities not be an option? So if their magnitudes are bigger than a maximum value normalize those velocities to magnitudes of that maximum value.

Comment: This is not an answer and may be a shot in the blue, but have you tried some kind of regression or polynomial interpolation?

Answer (score 2):

The Orocos-KDL library might have what you're looking for.

You can first construct a spline-path using `Path__RoundedComposite`. Each way point is defined with a desired position and orientation. Once the path has been defined, add velocity information using the `VelocityProfile` class. For a smooth motion, you've 2 options: spline and trapezoidal. If sudden start and stop is acceptable, you could go with rectangular too.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/snrkiwi/orocos-kdl/blob/master/orocos_kdl/examples/trajectory_example.cpp) from their official repository.

Once you've the trajectory down, extract inverse position and velocity kinematics using KDL's inverse kinematics solvers (assuming you've defined your robot as a KDL chain).

The math underlying all this (for eg. adding timing law to a Cartesian path, rotation interpolation) is pretty interesting, but it might take some time to code all that yourself ... that'd be a great learning experience nonetheless.